# What is the difference between complete refresh and fast refresh in materialized view?

Tags: oracle, rdbms, materialized-views

I have materialized view in my own schema and the materialized view source is the other schema table but , this master table has 900 rows and i did some dml operations on this master table after that i will refresh this materialized view as you know , and i did some resarch " how can i refresh my own materialized view " and it says " you can do complete refresh or fast refresh " but i didnt understand these solutions meaning so my question is simple ;

What is the difference between complete refresh and fast refresh in MV ?

P.S:If my master table has 1 million or more rows , which one i should choose? (fast or complete)

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Did you try to read the Oracle documentation? "Fast refresh" is always preferable, but it has many conditions/requirements; you must check to see if they are met. Complete refresh means the entire view is calculated from scratch, and may take a long time. Fast refresh means only rows that are affected will be recalculated - sometimes this concept doesn't even make sense (in which case the view will not be fast refreshable). https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/refresh.htm#DWHSG015

Comment: Documentation and googling a bit would had helped you understanding these.

Comment: i was reading document but i didnt understand what they are saying :). Thank you for  your reply :) its helpful :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Complete Refresh" means you truncate entire materialized view and insert new data.

"Fast Refresh" means you update (or insert/delete) only the rows which have been changed on master tables.

And just as information "Force Refresh" mean, Oracle tries to make a Fast Refresh and if this is not possible then do "Complete Refresh"

Usually Fast Refresh is much faster than Complete Refresh but it has restrictions. You have to define `MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG` on master tables.

Here is a full list of restrictions [General Restrictions on Fast Refresh](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/basicmv.htm#DWHSG8201), there are quite many.

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! I understand :)

Comment: If we just call `DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('m_view_name' );` which one runs ?

Comment: It depends how MView was created. You cannot set it while refresh.

Answer (score 0):

As always it depends, so if possible try both and measure for your application. As a general rule the fast refresh is likely to be much faster provided that only a small part of the data has changed. If all the data has changed a complete refresh is better.

With the fast refresh Oracle keeps track of the changes for the base tables and applies the changes to the materialized view when it is refreshed. A complete refresh on the other hand rebuilds the materialized view from scratch. With millions of rows that will be expensive, but again it is impossible to pick the best option without knowing more about your application.